# How do I SPOOL output without reaching buffer limit when setting TERMOUT OFF doesnt work

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using SQL developer and trying to spool out a fair amount of data. The script stops part way through as the buffer overflow is exceeded.

I understand this is because the Script Output cannot handle this amount of data but the solution to this `SET TERMOUT OFF` does not work.

I've provided an example below to illustrate this command not working

```
SET TERMOUT OFF
/

DECLARE

   CURSOR C1 IS

   select distinct '1' NUMBERR from dual;

BEGIN


    for c1_rec in c1 loop

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(C1_REC.NUMBERR);

   END LOOP;

end;
```

Output:

```
1


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

As you can see, the '1' is still output to the Script Output indicating the SET TERMOUT isn't working

Comment: How does this demonstrate something not working? I'm confused... Based on the 'buffer overflow' part, are youi just looking for `set serveroutput on size unlimited`?

Comment: SET TERMOUT OFF should disable the output of 1 from DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE  but it doesn't

Comment: The buffer overflow limit is only for the script output. I'm trying to SET TERMOUT OFF to stop the script generating to the script output but still spool to a file. Setting the size to unlimited does not work unfortunately ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow  limit of 100000 bytes

Comment: You'll hit the same limit in the spool file though, it isn't the script output window that's causing that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the SQL*Plus documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG112), which largely applies to SQL Developer too:

> TERMOUT OFF does not affect output from commands you enter interactively

If you had `set termout off` in a script file and ran it with `@<script>` then it would suppress out the output; but it would still be trying to to write the same data if you were spooling.

If you're seeing `ORU-10027: buffer overflow` then you're trying to solve the wrong problem anyway; even spooling, you'd hit the same error - it would just appear in the file and not in the script output window.

The buffer relates to `dbms_output` itself:

```
set serveroutput on size 2000

begin
  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_random.string('a', 2001));
end;
/

ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 2000 bytes
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 32
...
```

To avoid that error set the buffer high enough for the amount of output you expect, or to its maximum for the Oracle and client version:

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited
```

but as you've seen that still caps you to 1000000 bytes in SQL Developer, up to version 18.2 anyway.

Even with termout off and spooling to a file, you'll still get

```
ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 1000000 bytes
```

reported in the file.

If you need more output than that then you could write the output to a temporary table and then query it after your PL/SQL block, perhaps. Or you could use `utl_file` to write to a file (which has to be on the server, not the client, which is a downside) instead of spooling. Or you could use SQL*Plus, which doesn't impose that limitation.

Comment: I think I may try UTL_FILE instead. The funny thing is, I remember when working on something else a couple of weeks ago I was spooling something that hit this limit and my Script Output said something along the lines of 'maximum buffer exceeded, continuing output in spool'.